# tensorflow: split tensor according to some delimiter

Tags: tensorflow

Say I have a tensor like:

```
ts = tf.constant([1,2,3,-1,3,4,5,-1,2])
```

How can I split the tensor into a list of tensor with `-1` as the delimiter and get the following

```
tf.constant([1,2,3])
tf.constant([3,4,5])
tf.constant([1,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the constant into strings and then split them as strings into the slices you desire, and afterwards you can transform them back into lists of numbers:

Here is the slicing step:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ts = tf.constant([1,2,3,-1,3,4,5,-1,2])
ts_slices = 
    tf.string_split(tf.reshape(tf.reduce_join(tf.as_string(ts)), 
    [-1]), delimiter='-1')
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(ts_slices.values)
```

This gives you:

```
array([b'23', b'345', b'2'], dtype=object)
```

Now you can convert into integers again.

I am not sure wether this is the best solution to this problem, but at least it will solve your problem.

Comment: This solution loses the leading 1 on the first chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution, you have to specify the number of chunks in advance. Hope this still helps.

Code (tested):

```
import tensorflow as tf

ts = tf.constant([ 1, 2, 3, -1, 3, 4, 5, -1, 1, 2 ] )
delimiter = tf.constant( [ -1 ] )

left_padded = tf.concat( [ delimiter, ts ], axis = 0 )
padded = tf.concat( [ delimiter, ts, delimiter ], axis = 0 )
begin = tf.squeeze( tf.where( tf.equal( padded, delimiter ) ), axis = -1 ) # get position of -1s
sizes = begin[ 1 : ] - begin[ : -1 ] # get sizes of chunks
chunks = tf.split( left_padded, sizes, num = 3 ) # have to pre-specify number of chunks
for i in xrange( len( chunks ) ):
    chunks[ i ] = chunks[ i ][ 1 : ] # get rid of leading -1s

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( [ chunks ] ) )
```

Outputs:

> [ [array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32),
>   array([3, 4, 5], dtype=int32),
>   array([1, 2], dtype=int32)]]

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from Sabine Maennel's answer, here's a fully contained solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def split_by_delimiter(ts, delimiter):
    """Split a tensor similarly to python's `str.split` method."""
    ts_str = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_join(tf.as_string(ts), separator=' '), [-1])
    ts_slices = tf.string_split(
        tf.string_split(ts_str, delimiter=str(delimiter)).values)

    result = tf.SparseTensor(
        ts_slices.indices,
        tf.string_to_number(ts_slices.values, out_type=tf.int64),
        ts_slices.dense_shape)

    return tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(result)
```